# HTML Email in iOS

Tags: html, ios, mobile, html-email

I am getting a line across a table I made in an html email. It is in the orange area. I'm not really sure what is causing is. There is no images in there. Here is my code for that table.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="625" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
      <td height="23" bgcolor="#f08122" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="23" bgcolor="#f08122"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#f08122" valign="middle" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF;" align="center"><span style="font-size:30px; line-height:36px; font-weight:bold;"><strong>Improve outcomes and empower patients with health logs</strong></span><br /><br />
        <span style="font-size:27px;">Order now and get <strong>10% more FREE!*</strong></span></td>
        <td width="23" bgcolor="#f08122"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="23" bgcolor="#f08122" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Here is the link to the actual email also if you wanted an active view: https://tagwebstore.com/email/tag-email-logbooks.html

Here is a screenshot of the html email from my iPhone.

[image]

The lines appear to be above and below the white text. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The borders appear when a background color or image is applied to individual table cells.

you can try:

1. Removing background colors or images from individual table rows and
   cells, and/or;
2. Nesting the problem table in a new table, featuring a background color that matches that of the inner table.

[**source**](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3585/iphone-fail-the-trouble-with-table-borders-and-html-email/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20CampaignMonitor%20%28Campaign%20Monitor%20Blog%20Combined%29)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to give that a try. That does make more sense to set the background color in the table and not in the cells.

Comment: Both of the suggestions worked like a charm. Can't believe it was that simple. Got to pay attention to the small details in HTML. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Also, setting style="display: block;" on the img element consistently helps all images position exactly, in tandem with the above suggestions.